# Setting the starting page of my app from config when the view is a partial view

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Currently my app has two config keys used to denote the default controller and default action to use when loading the application.

```
<add key="DefaultController" value="Dashboard" />
<add key="DefaultAction" value="Overview" />
```

The view that the Overview action method returns displays many different partial views with in it, there for when using my app the URL does not change often at all. My question is for one of my customers they require that the starting page when first visiting the app be one of those specific partial views rather than the default partial I currently show. What would be the best way to implement this and make it easily configurable?

EDIT: 
To give a better example the app loads with the following URL `www.myapp.com/dashboard/overview.` I would like it to load up initially to the following `www.myapp.com/dashboard/overview?v=home`. The `v=home`being the relative link that I use to pull up the partial view that renders in the overview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply put a key in the `<appSettings>` of the `Web.config` and read it using Razor:

```
@Html.RenderPartial(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["startupPartial"]);
```

Comment: Using a method such as this would allow me to display the partial view I need inside of the overview view? Because I use Javascript to handle displaying the partial views, not the .net 'RenderPartial()' method.